# XPath - get parent of text nodes with condition

Tags: xpath

```xml
<doc ok="yes">
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>
                aa
                <d ok="yes">
                    bb
                </d>
                cc
            </c>
        </b>
    </a>
    <e>
        ee
    </e>
    <f ok="no">
        no
    </f>
</doc>
```

I need to retrieve list of nodes using XPath, where each node must satisfy these conditions:

1. node has at least one child text node
2. if the node (or closest node in ancestor axis) has an attribute `"ok"`, the value must be `"yes"`
3. when any ancestor is a part of the result, exclude node

So in my sample I would like to get `<c>` and `<e>`. Node `<d>` is excluded because it is a child of `<c>`, which is a part of the result.

I've started with condition (1) using this expression `//*[count(./text()[normalize-space()])>0]`. It returns `<c>`, `<d>`, `<e>`  and `<f>`. I have no idea how to exclude `<d>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would devide this into 2 steps.
First, consider only condition number 1 and 2.

```
//*[text()[normalize-space()]]
   [
      ancestor-or-self::*[not(@ok)] 
        or 
      ancestor-or-self::*[@ok][1][@ok='yes']
    ]
```

Given XML in question as input, above xpath return 3 elements : `<c>`, `<d>`, and `<e>`.

Next step would be implementing the condition number 3. That can be done by repeating the same predicate that was used in the first step, but now for `ancestor::*` instead of current node. Then negate the repeated predicate using `not()` as we want the ancestor to fail the condition no 1 & 2 (we want ancestor of current node not being part of the result already) :

```
[not(
        ancestor::*[text()[normalize-space()]]
        [
            ancestor-or-self::*[not(@ok)] 
                or 
            ancestor-or-self::*[@ok][1][@ok='yes']
        ]
    )
]
```

Combining both steps together you get the following xpath :

```
//*[text()[normalize-space()]]
   [
      ancestor-or-self::*[not(@ok)] 
        or 
      ancestor-or-self::*[@ok][1][@ok='yes']
    ]
    [not(
            ancestor::*[text()[normalize-space()]]
            [
                ancestor-or-self::*[not(@ok)] 
                    or 
                ancestor-or-self::*[@ok][1][@ok='yes']
            ]
        )
    ]
```

Each of the outer predicate (`[]`) in the final xpath, in order, represents condition no 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: There is probably small typo here: ancestor*[text()[normalize-space()]], but otherwise it works like a charm, thank you